# std::priority_queue contain struct with functor

Tags: c++, data-structures, std

I want to add struct `HeapNode` to `std::priority_queue` using a functor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>   

using namespace std;

struct HeapNode
{
    bool operator()(const struct HeapNode &a,const struct HeapNode &b) const 
    {  
        return b.c>=a.c;  
    } 
    double c;     
    double v;     
}h;

int main()
{
    priority_queue<struct HeapNode,vector<struct HeapNode>,h> H;
    struct HeapNode a={1,2};
    struct HeapNode b={3,2};
    struct HeapNode c={6,2};
    H.push(a);
    H.push(b);
    H.push(c);
}
```

But has errors:

```
queue.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
queue.cpp:19:65: error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Sequence, class _Compare> class std::priority_queue’
  priority_queue<struct HeapNode,vector<struct HeapNode>,heapnode> H;
                                                                 ^
queue.cpp:19:65: note:   expected a type, got ‘heapnode’
queue.cpp:23:4: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘H’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  H.push(1);
    ^
queue.cpp:24:4: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘H’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  H.push(2);
    ^
queue.cpp:25:4: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘H’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  H.push(3);
    ^
```

I have researched the reference but I'm still confused about `std::priority_queue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h` designates an object with static storage duration. The priority_queue template expects a **type**. The error is quite clear on this:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list
```

Now, it's a bit strange (and inefficient)<sup>(1)</sup> that you use the type itself as a functor to compare it. I recommend splitting it:

```
struct HeapNode
{
    double c;     
    double v;     
};

struct HeapNodeCompare
{
    bool operator()(const struct HeapNode &a,const struct HeapNode &b) const 
    {  
        return b.c>=a.c;  
    } 
};
```

Now your queue can be defined simply as such:

```
priority_queue<HeapNode, vector<HeapNode>, HeapNodeCompare> H;
```

---

(1) I say inefficient because a functor has to be default constructed in order to be used. Your type has meaningful state that occupy storage. If you use the type itself as a functor, that's a bit wasteful. The separate type has no state and will occupy minimal storage.

Comment: is that for each comparison or just once? Maybe a 2 double waste is maintainable if it's just once?

Comment: @Default - Why pay for what is not used? You have to pay something in size when using functors, but two doubles that aren't at all related to the functors comparison are a waste. Also, using the same class as the data and the functor violates the single responsibility principle, which is worse.

Answer (score 0):

Your third argument of the `priority_queue` template instantiation is a global variable, not a type.
You declared the `struct HeapNode`, then declared global variable `h` to be of type `struct HeapNode`.  Replace `h` by `struct HeapNode` in your template instantiation.

Also, I think it's better to have a separate comparator-class instead of reusing your node class.  This is because the `priority_queue` will create an instance of your `struct HeapNode` to have the comparator.