# std::priority_queue contain struct with functor that contains a state

Tags: c++, templates, functor

There exists two excellent answers to questions about std::priority_queue containing [struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795181/stdpriority-queue-contain-struct-with-functor)/[class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657876/stdpriority-queue-containing-my-own-class):

What if I need those compare structs to hold a state, such as an object of ofstream?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define compare functor with constructor requiring state:

```
    struct Compare
    {
        State state;

        Compare(State state)
            : state(state)
        {
        }

        bool operator()(const Item& a, const Item& b)
        {
            ... // use state
        }
    };
```

and pass its instance constructed with required state to priority_queue [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue):

```
    priority_queue<Item, std::vector<Item>, Compare> queue(Compare(state));
```